# Does PHP Phalcon PHQL INSERT INTO supports ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: php, phalcon

Working on Phalcon 4.x with PHP 7.x, I am trying to do a PHQL query for INSERT.

```
$phql = "INSERT INTO example
(
    user_id,
    answer,
    date_last
) VALUES (
    :user_id:,
    :answer:,
    NOW(),
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answer = :answer:, date_last = NOW()";
```

Using `modelsManager`

```
$records  = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery(
    $phql,
    [
        'user_id'       => $parameters['user_id'],
        'answer'       => $parameters['answer']
    ]
);
```

However, Phalcon is throwing the following error.

> Syntax error, unexpected token ON, near to ' DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
> answer = 1, date_last = NOW()', when parsing: INSERT INTO

Anyone from Phalcon community that might know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Some references https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/2266/on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0):

I believe, as of this writing. It is not supported for PHQL. The solution I made is the following.

Use Phalcon's low-level Db adapter for mysql

```
$connection = new DbPdoMysqlAdapter($dbConfig);

$sql = "INSERT INTO example
        (
            user_id,
            answer,
            date_last
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            NOW()
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answer = ?, date_last = NOW()";

$result = $connection->query(
    $sql,
    [
        $parameters['user_id'],
        $parameters['answer'],
        $parameters['answer']
    ]
);

var_dump($result);
```

Works now! Reference https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/api/phalcon_db#db-abstractdb

Comment: You can also create your own dialect for the Upsert operation: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-phql#custom-dialect (follow the example for `GROUP_CONCAT`).